# cannot change color of action bar in android studio

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

my main activity extendeds AppCompatActivity. i cannot see anything wrong with these codes but my action bar color still doesn't change. help?

styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#008000</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml (i use a splashscreen that's why .MainActivity is not my launcher)

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: you are using app compat v7 with `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: yes i have import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the styles.xml as follow:-

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF9800</item> // This will be the color of your Actionbar
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF9800</item> 
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#FF9800</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) to see which color values you should set/override in your application/activity theme.
`<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>` will be for color of action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try This in your java file instead. Will work on runtime but works 100% irrespective of style used.

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new 
      ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary)));
}
```

Don't Forget to import required classes and change 'colorPrimary' with color of your choice.